# Oracle mystery with filtering a query on numbers

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have a piece of very simple SQL that I cannot make work...

```
DECLARE
 RESTORE_ID NUMBER;
 counts NUMBER;
BEGIN
RESTORE_ID := 100014;
SELECT COUNT(UPDATE_ID) INTO counts FROM TB_ENT WHERE UPDATE_ID = RESTORE_ID;
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(counts);
END;
```

If I run the above, the output is 0.

If I run it without the `RESTORE_ID` variable replacing the SELECT line with:

```
SELECT COUNT(UPDATE_ID) INTO counts FROM TB_ENT WHERE UPDATE_ID = 100014;
```

You guessed, the output is 1. Why??

Comment: is tb_ent.update_id a NUMBER type?  could it be a VARCHAR2?

Comment: UPDATE_ID is a NUMBER, and primary key of the table that is set by a SEQUENCE.

Comment: this works for me on oracle 11. you must have not shown a complete test case.  Do you have a column called RESTORE_ID in TB_ENT?

Comment: show the full code of the case that does not work and the one that does.

Comment: @kevinsky you hit the nail on the head! I do have a RESTORE_ID column in the table. That was it! Thank you!

Comment: In PL/SQL it's a good idea to use some variety of [Hungarian notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_notation) for variable names. This can be as simple as prepending each and every variable name with `v` - anything to keep the name of variables and database objects from colliding.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should avoid using the names of columns for your variables.  Here is your code rewritten to do that.  I also like aliases for tables as I feel it keeps queries with lots of joins shorter.

```
DECLARE
 vRESTORE_ID NUMBER;
 vcounts NUMBER;
BEGIN
vRESTORE_ID := 100014;
SELECT COUNT(te.UPDATE_ID) 
INTO vcounts 
FROM TB_ENT te 
WHERE te.UPDATE_ID = vRESTORE_ID;
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(vcounts);
END;
```

Comment: Further reading: [Column Name Precedence](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/nameresolution.htm#LNPLS2038) (and the rest of that section of the documentation).

Comment: startting local variables with lv_ or something similar is always helpful.